# How to add a button in your website to join Google class room?

Tags: google-classroom

I have integrated Google classroom API in my website and I want to add button against subject which will be shown to every student on his dashboard like "Join Classroom" On click this button, i wnat to redirect user to google classroom.

I googled but did not find any help. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Do you want the button to add the student to the class *and* then redirect the page to the classroom? Or just redirect to the classroom? Can you share your script for this so far?

Comment: just want to redirect the user to the classroom without a Gmail login?

Comment: To view a classroom you have to have a Google Account. How do you expect them to join the classroom without one?

Comment: I was just asking if possible without a Gmail login.

Comment: Your original question did not make that clear. No, unfortunately it isn't possible. In order to view or join a classroom the user needs to be logged in to a Google Account. This is so that only authorised users view the content of the classroom.